# Connect electric PAT tester via serial port

Tags: usb, serial

I have a fairly old portable appliance tester (Seaward Europa Plus), for which the only way to download data to a PC is a SR232 port.
I do have a SR232 to USB adapter, correctly installed and recognized by Windows 8.1 (communicating on com port 7), but I cant get any data out of it. I've tried TeraTerm and RealTerm on Windows 8.1 and Minicom on Debian, but none of them could get a single bit of data out of the tester.
Bear in mind that said tester has the command to download data to the PC.
Also, [the manual instruction](http://www.seaward.co.uk/downloads/Europa_Plus_Manual.pdf) states that, while it is adviced to use Seaward own program, data can be downloaded to any compatible programs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some USB-to-serial adapters use lower voltage (3V, or 5V) than the usual 15V used in fairly old equipment. While this is inside the spec, sometimes it just doesn't work. The other problem is that you have to select the correct baud rate, parity etc.

Comment: Manuals says the port uses 5V, and I've selected the correct baud rate, parity and start and stop bits as per manual.

Comment: *"Manuals says the port uses 5V"* -- Where is that? What are the "Download Options" (as described on p47 of the manual) that you have configured?  Have you tried both null-modem and straight-through cables?  @dirkt -- *"Fairly old equipment"* has nothing to do with the voltage levels.  It's either TTL logic voltages (straight from the UART) or RS-232 levels (from a transceiver/line-driver chip).

Comment: @sawdust: Age has plenty do to with voltage levels, because back in the, say, 80s *all* RS-232 interfaces used 15V (or at least more than 10V), only later they started to use TTL logic levels, too, and today you can see basically any voltage level around 3V in embedded systems for the debugging console.

Comment: @dirkt -- You are incorrect because you are conflating a UART interface (TTL levels) with RS-232.  They are related, but not the same.  You simply cannot connect a RS-232 port to a TTL UART port: incompatible voltages & polarity.  The 3.3V UART/USART interfaces found on development boards are due to (a) save the cost and space of providing transceiver ICs, and (b) provide flexibility in use of that interface, e.g. connect the appropriate transceiver/line-driver and turn it into a RS-232, RS-422, RS-485, or use it as a SPI or infrared interface.  IOW RS-232 has not changed its voltage levels.